# mouse hover in HTML function to pop out or zoom in pic

Tags: html, mouseover, onmouseover, mouseout, mousehover

I am an oracle guy and am struggling to write an HTML function, I would really appreciate your help. 
What i want to achieve is i have a 4 picture or one pictures with 4 parts, and once the mouse over each part it needs to pop out or get zoomed in. 
[image]
ultimately i want once the mouse hover any part to pop out,
FYI i can have the part saved as pictures. so the original picture will be split into 4 parts.
please share the code to do so, or if you have any information please let me know, your help is highly appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: show your related css code ..

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way to achieve the pop effect would be to apply a CSS 2D scale transform when hovering over the element.  Something to this effect:

```css
.part {
  background-color: #ddf;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 10px;  
  border: 1px solid #333;
  transition: 0.15s;
}
.part:hover {
  transform: scale(1.02);
}
```

```html
<div class='part'>Part 1</div>
<div class='part'>Part 2</div>
<div class='part'>Part 3</div>
<div class='part'>Part 4</div>
```